# Transactional NTFS wrapper

Tags: c#, io, wrapper, txf

I'm using transactional NTFS wrapper that is available on msdn [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/txfmanaged) to support atomic transactions of file system operations, the available example only shows how to work with transactedFiles but I need also to create, move and copy transacted Directories, I don't know how to use TransactedDirectory Class, can you please help?
I tried this code but it doesn't seem to be correct:

```
   if (Transaction.Current == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Must be within a transaction scope");
        }
        using (TransactionScope folderTransaction = new TransactionScope(Transaction.Current))
        {
            TransactedDirectory.StartTxFResource("D:\\New");

           folderTransaction.Complete();
           TransactedDirectory.StopTxFResource("D:\\New");

        }
```

it gives an error "access denied, the folder is being used by another process".

Answer (score 0):

Under which User Account is your process running? Check if it has access to the `D:\New` folder.

For a quick check, run the process as Administrator (Right click myprocess.exe > Run As Administrator), and if it works then, you should either set the correct permissions, or setup your code to require admin level access.